# Can you identify this aircraft at Chilliwack(YCW)?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This aircraft is sitting at YCW, with no visible registration numbers.  Can you identify it? [image]

Answer (score 33):

It's a [De Havilland DH104 Dove](http://jetphotos.net/showphotos.php?regsearch=N4913V). It did have a registration of [N4913V](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?nNumberTxt=N4913V) but it was cancelled in 2012.

[The Dove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Dove) is an airliner that can seat 8 passengers, and 542 were produced from 1946 to 1967.

Comment: Short, yet perfect answer. Pit that OP isn't able to accept it.